# Permissible combinations of colour states for gluons

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, lie-algebra, representation-theory, gluons, color-charge

My lecturer has said that there are 8 types of gluons (I'm assuming that the repetition of $r\bar{b}$ is a typo that is meant to be $r\bar{g}$)

$$r\bar{b}, b\bar{r}, r\bar{g}, g\bar{r}, g\bar{b}, b\bar{g}$$
which I'm fine with. 
However what I don't understand is that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(r\bar{r}-g\bar{g})\text{ and }\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(r\bar{r}+g\bar{g}-2b\bar{b})$$

are allowed, as she states later that *"we are not allowed colour-neutral combinations e.g. $r\bar{r}$"*

How is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(r\bar{r}-g\bar{g})$ not colour neutral? If you were to measure it surely it would collapse into either $r\bar{r}$ or $g\bar{g}$ state, which are colour neutral?

Also what forbids the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(b\bar{b}+g\bar{g})$ and other similar combinations if $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(r\bar{r}-g\bar{g})$ is allowed?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89173/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The color language is not really well-suited to understand why there are eight gluons. Here's why, however:

The gluon field transforms in the [adjoint representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation_of_a_Lie_algebra) of the color gauge group $\mathrm{SU}(3)$. The adjoint representation is a representation on the vector space of the generators of $\mathrm{SU}(3)$, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(3)$. An explicit realization of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ is given by the [Gell-Mann matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices) $\lambda_i$, and it is simply a fact that $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ is an eight-dimensional vector space, and that there are hence eight independent gluons/Gell-Mann matrices.

To assign now colors to the gluon fields $G_i$, which are the real coefficients of the expansion of the $\mathfrak{su}(3)$-valued gluon field $G$ as $G = \sum_i G_i \lambda_i$, we look at the interaction term with the quarks, which is proportional to
$$ \bar q G q $$
and known to be color-neutral (more formally, invariant under an $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ gauge transformation). With the chosen realization of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ as the Gell-Mann matrices, we choose the basis of the corresponding (three-dimensional) fundamental representation for the quarks to be the basis of "colors", i.e. $q = (q_r,q_b,q_g)^T$, where $q_c$ is the $c$-colored part of the quark state. In particular, a pure red state is given be $(1,0,0)^T$, for example.

Now, insert $q = (q_r,q_b,q_g)$ into the interaction term and look only at what $\lambda_1$ does to this, i.e. explicitly compute $\bar q G_1\lambda_1 q$. The result is $\bar r G_1 b + r G_1 \bar b$ (up to normalization). From this we infer that $G_1$, in this realization is a gluon field corresponding to an equal mixture of red-antiblue and blue-antired, i.e. $\bar r b + \bar b r$. We would also find a $\bar r b - \bar b r$ gluon, allowing us to change into the choice of color basis of the question, where we have $\bar r b$ and $\bar b r$, by forming linear combinations like $(\bar r b - \bar b r) + (\bar r b + \bar b r)$.

The statement "color-neutral gluons are not allowed" is *technically correct* in the sense that the gluons together from the adjoint representation rather than a trivial representation. However, it does *not* translate into the naive meaning of "writing down combinations human color intuition would describe as colorless is not allowed", and that's why we also get a gluon $\bar r r - \bar g g$.

**tl;dr**: The color charges and color combinations of the strongly charged particles are *not* literally governed by human color intuition, but arise from assigning color rather arbitrarily to the representations of $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ the particles transform under.

**Also**, note that the "color" of a state is *not measureable*, as a "red state" is changed by a $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ gauge transformation into a "blue state", and states which are related by gauge transformation are *not physically distinguishable*, see also [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/176484/50583).