# What's the relation between representation theory and mass / electric charge?

Tags: mass, charge, gauge-theory, representation-theory

This is a follow-up on [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/246148/86781) answer, where ACuriousMind wrote

> Formally, both the mass and the charge classify certain irreducible representations of the Poincaré group and the circle group, respectively.

I understand the basics of representation theory, and I know the $U(1)$ gauge transformations of the QED Lagrangian (I suppose that's the connection between electric charge and the circle group $U(1)$). I also have seen the basics of non-abelian gauge transformations.

However, I wasn't aware that there is a connection between representation theory and the conserved electric charge. Moreover, I had no idea that mass had anything to do with irreps of the Poincaré group.

What are the details of that connection? Why do mass and charge *classify* irreps?

Comment: One-particle states are irreducible representations of the Poincare group. What classifies representations of the Poincare group?

Comment: Key words: (Quadratic) Casimir operators, and Schur's lemma which tells you that they're constant on irreps.

Comment: @Danu and Prahar Thanks for the hints, gonna follow those leads.