# Experimental evidence for color charge via Electron-Positron-Annihilation experiments

Tags: particle-physics, quarks

In Electron-Positron-Annihilation R, the ratio of the hadronic cross section to the muon cross section, is calculated as the sum of charges squared, multiplied by 3 to factor in the 3 colors. I know that this describes the experiments pretty well, but I have some points I do not understand (Referring to PDG-report in Chin. Phys. C, 38, 090001 (2014), https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/reviews/rpp2020-rev-cross-section-plots.pdf).

1.) First of all doesn’t this contradict statements like given in [Is color charge a quantum mechanical observable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176478/is-color-charge-a-quantum-mechanical-observable) by e.g. @AcuriousMind : "“red, blue or green" quarks do not exist. Objects in the theory that are related by a gauge transformation are literally the same, there is no difference between a "red quark" and a "green quark" - a quark is a quark is a quark.”

2.) A minor point:
It looks like R does not directly goes up to the next higher value after the respective J/Ψ($c\bar{c}$), ϒ(1S)($b\bar{b}$) mesons but stays put at the lower value up to Ψ(2S), ϒ(4S). Why such a delay?

Comment: 1.) no contradiction; you *can* make indirect inferences on something not directly observable.  2) list question. Are you talking about Fig 52.3? Be more explicit, as your question is unclear. Is this a chat on charmonium?

Comment: Yes, Fig. 52.3, in particular the KEDR data up to 3.7 GeV

Comment: The free charm threshold for DD is at 3.74 GeV; that's the one that counts for R, not the narrow ψs. The next ψ is above it.